# Hashing and Salting Passwords with Spring Security 3

Tags: java, spring, hash, spring-security, saltedhash

How can I hash passwords and salt them with Spring Security 3?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Programmatic-ally you would do it as follows:

In your application-context.xml (defined in web.xml under `contextConfigLocation`) file define the bean (this example uses `md5`).

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder" />
```

Then Autowire the password encoder:

```
@Autowired
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
```

In your method or wherever you want to hash and salt.

```
passwordEncoder.encodePassword("MyPasswordAsString", "mySaltAsStringOrObject");
```

The above call should return a salted hash (as a `String`).

That should do it. I'm assuming you can figure out the jar's you'll need.

**UPDATE**

It should go without saying that using MD5 is not the best idea. Ideally you should use SHA-256 at least. This can be done with the [`ShaPasswordEncoder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/ShaPasswordEncoder.html).

Replace the MD5 bean config above with:

```
<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
     <constructor-arg value="256"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: +1: this is the way most people do it (and the correct one IMO)

Comment: Thanks Simeon, I think kamaci has moved on though, hasn't accepted any answer.

Comment: why not using Spring beans, like
<security:password-encoder hash="sha"/>
?

Comment: Obviously though you wouldn't use MD5.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, upvoted, but _please_ update your answer to reference a secure hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 8):

Simplest seems to be Spring Security 3.1 assuming no constraints on the way hashing should be done:

```
<bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" users-by-username-query="select username,password, enabled from users where username=?" authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, ur.authority from users u, user_roles ur where u.username = ur.username and u.username =?"/>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>


@Controller
@Stateless
public class UsersEJB {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "somePU")
    private EntityManager em;
    @Transactional
    public void create(Users users) {
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(users.getPassword());
        users.setPassword(hashedPassword);
        em.persist(users);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of creating a new instance of BCryptPasswordEncoder you should @Autowire to the bean with id "encoder"

Comment: This is nice, however w/o any explanation it's not entirely helpful.

Answer (score 6):

easiest way, as [documented](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#core-services-password-encoding):

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" >
        <password-encoder hash="sha">
            <salt-source user-property="username"/>
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

HTH