# Spring Security:password encoding in DB and in applicationContext

Tags: database, encoding, passwords, spring-security, config

Have config (applicationContext-security.xml):

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
    <password-encoder hash="sha"/>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

from other side have SQLs from my `dataSource`(it's [JdbcDaoImpl](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.html)):

```
...
    public static final String DEF_USERS_BY_USERNAME_QUERY =
            "select username,password,enabled " +
            "from users " +
            "where username = ?";
...
```

There is now word about `sha` in this code,so password selected from standard Spring Security `users` table not encoded.

Perhaps, I should provide some `sha` attribute for `password` column in my hibernate mapping config here:

```
<class name="model.UserDetails" table="users">
    <id name="id">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="username" column="username"/>
    <property name="password" column="password"/>
    <property name="enabled" column="enabled"/>
    <property name="mail" column="mail"/>
    <property name="city" column="city"/>
    <property name="confirmed" column="confirmed"/>
    <property name="confirmationCode" column="confirmation_code"/>

    <set name="authorities" cascade="all" inverse="true">
        <key column="id" not-null="true"/>
        <one-to-many class="model.Authority"/>
    </set>

</class>
```

For now password saved to DB as is,but should be encoded.

How to friend `applicationContext` config and DB queries to be the same password encoding?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you are choosing a hashing system yourself, rather than building an app using an existing database which already contains hashed passwords, then you should make sure your hashing algorithm also uses a salt. Don't just use a plain digest.

A good choice is bcrypt, which we now support directly in Spring Security 3.1 via the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` (implemented using [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/)). This automatically generates a salt and concatenates it with the hash value in a single String.

Some databases have built-in support for hashing (e.g. [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/pgcrypto.html)). Otherwise, you need to hash the password yourself before passing it to JDBC:

```java
String password = "plaintextPassword";
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
```

That's all you need to do to encode the passwords when you create a user.

For authentication, you would use something like:

```xml
<bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>

<bean id="authProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
  <property name="userDetailsService" ref="yourJdbcUserService" />
  <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder" />
</bean>
```

Comment: about salt,I know, it's the next phase of my security challenge))

Comment: If you use something like bcrypt, then it is automatically handled for you, so there isn't really any challenge :-). You don't have to handle the salt yourself.

Comment: @LukeTaylor Could you show how it would be configured in the applicationContext-security.xml?

Comment: @falsarella You mean for authentication? I've added the config for an AuthenticationProvider bean.

Comment: @LukeTaylor,do you consider `org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder` in your example?thank you.

Comment: I am wondering how BCryptPasswordEncoder works. Does it generate one salt for all passwords or a separate salt for each ? If so where does it store the user-salt ?

Comment: Or maybe I am mixing Hashing with Encoding ?!

Comment: Another question I am asking myself why doesn't Spring Security provide a Hashing Algorithm rather than encrypting one.

Comment: BCrypt isn't an encryption algorithm and the salt is stored in the same string. Perhaps the [Wikipedia article on Bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) will help.

Answer (score 12):

A little more explanation on the accepted answer. Hope it helps someone.

Hash the password yourself before putting it to database:

```
String password = "plaintextPassword";
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
```

Add BCryptPasswordEncoder bean to your security-config.xml

Add passwordEncoder as a property to Authentication Provider class. Autowire it or provide setter and getter methods.

```
@AutoWired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
```

Get the property while you authendicate user for login

```
<bean id="dbAuthenticationProvider" class="mypackage.auth.spring.DBAuthenticationProvider" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="routingDataSource"></property>
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder" />
    <property name="passwordQuery"
        value="select password as password from tbl where username=:username">
    </property> 
</bean>
```

And in the authenticating class match both passwords

```
 new BCryptPasswordEncoder().matches(plainTextPasswdFromUserInput, hashedPasswdFromDb)
```

Comment: matches method was what I was looking.

Answer (score 5):

Using Spring Security 3.1, try this:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="service">
        <password-encoder hash="sha"/>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="dataSource" ...>
    ...
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="service" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        ...
</beans:bean>
```

What's new: `authentication-provider` points to `service` and `service` points to `datasource`.

**Edit:** In Java you will have to encode the password with something like this:

```
DigestUtils.sha(request.getParameter("password"));
```

**Warn:** Be careful! Do not mix *SHA* with *MD5*!

If you set the `password-encoder` of the `authentication-provider` as *SHA*, you need to encode in Java the same way to keep consistent. But if you enconde in Java as *MD5*, as the sample you found, do not forget to set the *hash* to "md5". [DigestUtils](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html) also provides md5 encoder:

```
DigestUtils.md5(request.getParameter("password"));
```

Comment: yes,I know,but you didn't ask on my question how to provide,that user password saved encoded to DB

Comment: Well, I don't know what you mean by provide, but to persist, I have used [DigestUtils](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html).

Comment: @sergionni: sorry, but I don't know a configuration of applicationContext to automatically save the password encoded, as I said, I have used DigestUtils from Apache commons.

Comment: thank you for point,never heard about digest.So,should I provide digest in order my password to be encrypted?this example:http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/basic.html

Comment: ahhh,looks like I understand, I should encode my password in Java DAO class, when persisting my `UserDetails` entity with following:`MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5"); ...`here is full explanation:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821082/spring-security-encypt-md5

Comment: @sergionni Look at my edit, I wrote a sample to show how the DigestUtils implementation makes it easy to encode. Simple and clean.

Comment: falsarella, thank your for one more hint in encoding and digesting.This code looks short and clean.

Answer (score 5):

In a simple way can you do something like in applicationContext-security.xml

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
   <authentication-provider>
    <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
       users-by-username-query="
          select username,password, enabled 
          from principal where username=?" 
       authorities-by-username-query="
          select p.username, a.authority from principal p, authority a
          where p.id = a.principal_id and p.username=?" 
    />
   </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager> 

  <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
```

In Java

```
public static String encodePasswordWithBCrypt(String plainPassword){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(plainPassword);
}
```

Then test it

```
System.out.println(encodePasswordWithBCrypt("fsdfd"));
```

Answer (score 4):

Just a tip for doing it with annotations

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@PropertySource("classpath://configs.properties")
public class SecurityContextConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Autowired
@Qualifier("userDetailsService")
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());
}


@Bean(name = "passwordEncoder")
public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();     
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is right. 
I tested it with **spring 3.1** and **BCrypt** encode algorithm.

When create a user.

```
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
userEntity.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userEntity.getPassword()));
userDao.save(userEntity);
```

When the user login, Remember, use the plain password (**not hashed**). just like:

```
Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword());
Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate(request);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
```

Here is security-config:

```
    <bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>

<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
        <property name="hideUserNotFoundExceptions" value="false" />
        <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder" />
    </bean>
```

Hope it will help somebody!

Answer (score 1):

with 3.1.x this mapping doesnt work for auth.
Working way is:

```
<beans:bean id='bCryptPasswordEncoder' class='org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder'></beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
          <password-encoder ref="bCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```