# How to implement customized SHA-256 salt per user login/out with db spring 3.1 security?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, salt

I am reading the doc [Spring 3.1 security documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html) extensively, but I can't find answers to all my questions.

In a spring web application, based on form login (user + pwd), I want to salt user passwords with SHA-256, using a random salt for each user. This means I have to save the salt and the hashed password in my database for each user. No issue so far.

1. It seems clear that I have to implement my own `UserDetailsService` to fetch my user information's from my database and configure it in my `spring-security.xml`.
2. It seems like I will have to add an extra `getSalt()` method on top of my implementation of `UserDetails` to make it available when checking the login provided by the user against the stored hashed password.

Then the situation becomes unclear. I should intercept login requests. From section 6.4.3, it seems like Spring will map the user submitted credentials to an `Authentication` object and submit it to an `AuthenticationManager`.

My questions are:

i) What implementation of `Authentication` will Spring submit to the `AuthenticationManager`? How do I retrieve the name and password?

ii) It seems like I would have to implement my own `AuthenticationManager`. At each call of `authenticate(...)`, I would fetch the login name and password, fetch `UserDetails` from the database. Then, hash the provided pwd with the corresponding salt and compare with the database hashed item. Correct?

iii) The `AuthenticationManager` API also has a `supports(...)` method. How should it be implemented?

iv) How should `Authentication` and `AuthenticationManager` be configured?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a particular reason/requirement you chose to salt your user passwords?

Comment: @Andre To make sure that if someone breaks the database, they won't have access to the source passwords.

Comment: That's what I thought. I was just wondering if you need to actually store the salt. I've come across BCrypt a bunch of times and ended up using it with Spring Security; it works just fine. Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8528804/323807

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must not be reading your question properly, but Spring Security offers salted passwords out of the box:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/core-services.html#d0e3021

If an 8-bit salt is insufficient, you are able to inject your own SaltSource into the DaoAuthenticationProvider.  The manual actually strongly recommends this.

Comment: I guess I did not go far enough in the documentation. Thanks.