# How to retrieve user password in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

How to retrieve user password in Spring Security (java configuration)?
I tried this:

```
@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.eraseCredentials(false);
    }
```

and this:

```
Object credentials = authentication.getCredentials();
```

but the credentials returned are always null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UserDetails getPassword returns null in spring security 3.1. How to get password of currently logged in user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303081/userdetails-getpassword-returns-null-in-spring-security-3-1-how-to-get-password)

Comment: No. There is a solution there for xml configuration, not for java

Comment: [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#core-services-erasing-credentials) says that Spring Security will attempt to clear any sensitive credentials information from the Authentication object which is returned by a successful authentication request. It also specifies that you  can disable that feature. Check it out.

Comment: It does not say how to do that

Comment: @sva605 Have you managed to get password?