# Spring Security - Get clear password on authentication and re-encrypt them

Tags: java, spring, encryption, spring-security

I have a user table containing both MD5 (legacy stuff) and BCrypt password. I would like to migrate MD5 password to BCrypt, without bruteforce them. I thought about re-encrypt passwords on successful authentication.

However (so far in my investigation), I can only get clear password (from login page) if I disable `erase-credentials` in `authentication-manager` declaration. In this case, I have access to credentials information not only from my custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`, but from anywhere in my application as well (using `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` ).

Is there a way to access clear password on successful authentication only ? Or do you know a better way to re-encrypt passwords without asking for user manipulation (password change, etc.) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to create a password encoder that accepts both legacy MD5 hash and value from new, better (BCrypt) encoder, and migrates MD5 hash when finding one.

```java
@Component
public class MigratingPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder {

    @Autowired
    private org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder; // new encoder (BCrypt)

    @Autowired
    private Md5PasswordEncoder legacyEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao; // where password hashes are stored

    public String encodePassword(String rawPass, Object salt) {
        return passwordEncoder.encode(rawPass);
    }

    public boolean isPasswordValid(String encPass, String rawPass, Object salt) {
        if (legacyEncoder.isPasswordValid(encPass, rawPass, salt)) {
            // MD5 hash found here, save a new hash instead
            userDao.updatePassword(encPass, passwordEncoder.encode(rawPass));
            return true;
        }
        return passwordEncoder.matches(rawPass, encPass);
    }
}
```

Deprecation note: This uses the old `PasswordEncoder` interface in `org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding` package, but it is quite unavoidable since since `Md5PasswordEncoder` also uses that interface.

Credit: Inspired from the answer of [Spring security 3.1.4 and ShaPasswordEncoder deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240744/spring-security-3-1-4-and-shapasswordencoder-deprecation).