# AES Password Encoder in Spring acegi security for Java based application

Tags: spring-security

We are using spring acegi security for user password encoding and authentication, in past we were using SHAPasswordEncoder but our need it to make it AES compliant, I don't find any AES PasswordEncoder in Spring acegi security, please suggest somebody if spring supports AES or it has some plan in future to support AES. Thanks, Shailendra Singh

Comment: You shouldn't be using Acegi anymore. It has long passed it's end of life and has several unpatched security holes.

Comment: suggested by Luke - use BCrypt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521251/spring-securitypassword-encoding-in-db-and-in-applicationconext/8528804#8528804