# Implementing hash and salt in Spring 3 security

Tags: java, security, spring-security, salt, password-hash

I understand the idea of hash+salt when I create new entry to dtb. If I have some fixed string for the salt it might not be hard to implement it, but how to do it, when I want to use for example user's birthday as a salt? Saving that password to database is easy, but how to hash this during login? I've googled this piece of code for my `applicationContext-security.xml` file, where they use `username` value for salt:

```xml
<!-- authentication from database -->
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service
            data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="
          select username,password, enabled 
          from users where username=?"authorities-by-username-query="
          select u.username, ur.authority from users u, user_roles ur 
          where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.username =?  " />
    <security:password-encoder hash="sha-256">
        <security:salt-source user-property="username" />
        </security:password-encoder-->
    </security:authentication-provider>

</security:authentication-manager>
```

So if I understand it correctly, it means, that if I would like to use user's birthday as salt, I would have to have it stored in my dtb, pull it out from dtb and then use it as a salt? It doesn't make sense to me, because if I have in my `users` table columns `username`, `password`, `birthday`, then the password can be hashed, but for the possible attacker is it quite clear, that the `birthday` value will be used as salt. Is there something I'm missing or does it really work so?

Comment: Something like [BCrypt](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8528804/241990) is the preferred option these days. The salting is done internally, so you don't have to worry about it, and it's more secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of using salts is to protect user's password in case of a database dump from a hacker. Because a hash is a one way conversion (you can't reverse the conversion to get the plain text password) hackers are using dictionary of hash to guess user's password (using common passphrases). So adding a salt will add an additional protection layer against this type of attack.

From wikipedia:

[Dictionary attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionary_attacks)

[Rainbow table attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)

Answer (score 1):

The salt is not sensitive information, it doesn't matter if it is disclosed. The salt simply prevents rainbow table attacks on hashes. Note that salt should have a fairly high level of entropy, and the birthday may not be as secure as, say, 32 bytes from `SecureRandom`.